# Redirect full address on all domains to one main domain using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Let's say I have two domain names :

1. maindomain.com
2. parkeddomain.com

Using .htaccess I would like to add www to all URL requests and also redirect all from parked domain to the main domain. In simple words I intend to redirect all below address forms using **.htaccess** :

```
http://maindomain.com/someurl00/subsitepage00/
http://parkeddomain.com/someurl00/subsitepage00/
http://www.parkeddomain.com/someurl00/subsitepage00/
```

**TO :**

```
http://www.maindomain.com/someurl00/subsitepage00/
```

I have tried the below method but it is not working properly :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parkeddomain\.com$ [NC][OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.parkeddomain\.com$ [NC][OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?parkeddomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: It is working but do you have any idea why URLs are converted like this: `http://www.maindomain.com//someurl00/subsitepage00/` There is an extra "/" after the main domain. I tried `http://www.maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}` but I still get the extra "/". Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I already did remove that / before %{REQUEST_URI} but don't why it was not working in my current browser. Might be related to cache. Just tried it on another computer and it's working like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes indeed it is due to browser caching 301 URIs.